# ROC plot not with boolean values

Tags: r

Do i need here TRUE/FALSE value here? As far as i know, to make a roc plot, you have to match Positive cases not only with boolean values. And after code below i got this error and i do not know how to cope with it :/

```
 roc <- function(pred.s, true.y)
{
  cutoff <- Inf  # start with all instances classified as negative
  tp <- fp <- 0
  tn <- sum(2-as.integer(true.y))  # all negative instances
  fn <- sum(as.integer(true.y)-1)  # all positive instances
  rt <- data.frame()

  sord <- order(pred.s, decreasing=TRUE)  # score ordering
  #pred.s[sord]
  #as.integer(true.y[sord])
  for (i in 1:length(sord))
  {
    if (pred.s[sord] < cutoff)
    {
      rt <- rbind(rt, data.frame(tpr=tp/(tp+fn), fpr=fp/(fp+tn), cutoff=cutoff))
      cutoff <- pred.s[sord]
    }

    p <- as.integer(true.y[sord])-1  # next positive classified as positive
    n <- 2-as.integer(true.y[sord])  # next negative classified as positive
    tp <- tp+p
    fp <- fp+n
    tn <- tn-n
    fn <- fn-p
  }
  rt <- rbind(rt, data.frame(tpr=tp/(tp+fn), fpr=fp/(fp+tn), cutoff=cutoff))
}
```

```
pred.s <- labels #Factor w/ 5 levels "1", "2", "3", "4", "5":
true.y<- krkModified$grupa #Factor w/ 5 levels "1", "2", "3", "4", "5":
order(pred.s, decreasing=TRUE)
myroc<-roc(pred.s,true.y)
```

```
Error in if (pred.s[sord] < cutoff) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed 
In addition: Warning message: 
In Ops.factor(pred.s[sord], cutoff) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
```

After changing factors to character with these commands

```
pred.s <- data.frame(lapply(labels, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
true.y <- data.frame(lapply(krkModified$grupa, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

i got this error now and i do not know exactly whot does it mean

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```